# Can anyone make sense of what’s happening with this framing?

Tags: framing, load-bearing

[image]

Basically the horizontal boards are sandwiched between 2x4's on either side. House is a 1925 cape, but the bathroom is newer (maybe 10-15 years ago)

This is an interior wall with plaster/lathe behind it. Trying to determine wtf is going on here and if I can just remove it to frame out for my medicine cabinet.

[Here are some further photos](https://imgur.com/a/YtR9AQ3) taken while opening the wall.

Comment: It’s not lathe board they are horizontal 2x4s

Comment: Sorry maybe it looks that way from the pic, but it is not lathe board. The lathe is behind it (with the plaster squeezed through) Check pic number 7 in the album I posted. That board you’re looking at is the top one in that stack. It spans the entire depth of the bay.

Comment: I removed some more drywall. Hopefully this makes it a little more clear. https://imgur.com/a/sMOb0d3?s=sms  The 2x4 (newer one) top left is loose and doesn’t seem to be supporting anything at all.

Comment: Hope you don't mind I moved your new pic into the question and removed references to the old one.   Hopefully someone will recognize this framing.  I sure don't, it looks like an attempt to use up available lumber when renovating the bathroom without buying more.  If that's the case you may need to  open up about 3 feet wide of wall floor to ceiling and replace this mess with new studs.  That will also allow you to easily move wires and supply power to the cabinet if needed.

Comment: You should try not to get plaster dust into the drain and the moving parts of the faucet and tape measure.  If you're planning to replace the basin anyway, all the more reason to just open up the whole wall and put in new framing and  blocking for whatever you want.

Comment: What's below the opening appears to be lath (not lathe). But it looks like there might be a solid piece at the bottom of the opening (green edge). I have no explanation and can't see how it's mounted well enough to guess

Comment: The green edge and every horizontal piece below it are the full depth of the stud bay and are not lath boards.

Comment: The more I see the less I understand!

Comment: Possibly there used to be a window here?

Comment: Doubtful. It’s an interior wall backing up to a closet in a bedroom.

Comment: @jay613 You removed the first sentence from the post when moving the picture inline. Also, the linked image was an album with more pictures, perhaps leave the link intact and keep the image inline?

Comment: @matt a reference to a small hole and pictures of/through it taken before it was enlarged to provide a much better view.

Comment: Looks to me like you have some studs sitting on *top* of some kind of blocking, the purpose of which is unknown.

Comment: I vote that understanding what is going on there and sharing it here is *by itself* good enough reason to open up the entire wall.  Just the curiosity!   Finding a way to do your cabinet is a bonus. Do I get a vote? :)

Comment: @jay613 With that outlet to the right OP would likely only need to open a little farther to the right and then to the corner on the left side (which was included in the OG link to the photo album you removed...).

Comment: This _definitely_ calls for more exploratory surgery. Also, it's an interior wall _now_ but it could have been an exterior wall in the past...

Comment: At the behest of @matt. I put back a link that I removed to an earlier album of photos taken while OP cut open the wall.  And to matt.'s credit, there is in fact something interesting there!   Just below the opening there is a 2 inch PVC pipe going through the back of the wall.  What could that be?  If it's the vent for the basin, and if the installer decided to run it exposed through the adjacent closet rather than through that stack of boards, it would be good to understand why.  25NJ can you look in the closet and tell us where that pipe goes?

Comment: @jay613 I didn't order/command you to restore the link. I just pointed out that it had been removed and by doing so it removed some valuable information. I do think restoring it was the correct course of action though and I appreciate you doing so. I prefer not to rollback other members edits. Thank you.

Comment: I’ll try to take some more pics in the wall, but it definitely was never an exterior wall. The PVC is a vent that does go into the closet but makes an immediate left, presumably to connect to the main vent behind the toilet.

Comment: Here are some more pics (scroll to end of album) https://imgur.com/a/YtR9AQ3      Including a drawing of what I believe the framing looks like. Any more thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not all that uncommon to see and it's reasoning may be difficult to decipher.

The 2x4s could be there for a myriad of reasons, to pack out an old window if this used to be an exterior wall or to simply use what materials were available on hand at the time.

If you're dead set on a recessed medicine cabinet in this exact location you'll likely need to open wall up more to the right alongside the outlet as it is unlikely they extend past that and then all the way to the corner on the left (pictured in the original photo album).

Doing so would allow you to remove them and replace the studs that have been cut. Only proceed with this if your comfortable or hire it out to a qualified carpenter.

The other option is to add some backing while you have the wall opened and mount a nice surface mount unit instead.