# Can anyone make sense of this framing (Part 2)

Tags: framing, load-bearing

Follow up to my original question here:

[Can anyone make sense of what’s happening with this framing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/292054/can-anyone-make-sense-of-what-s-happening-with-this-framing)

I registered but was unable to add a new comment for some reason. Anyway, here is a link to the album, where I added a few more pics of what I found when I opened up the wall a little further.

https://imgur.com/a/YtR9AQ3

I also included a rough diagram of what I believe is going on. Looks like they built some janky blocking to possibly support the box for the light fixture? I don't know the reasoning, but it looks to me like I can safely cut out what I need to frame out for my cabinet. Thoughts?

Comment: Is it possible that wall was an outside wall at one time?  It is a janky build, but the wood is of structural size, so just cutting it out and not adding extra supports might not be in your best interest.  Drywall is easy to replace, the roof might not be.

Comment: The problem is whether this is a load bearing wall, with the load path dependent on this wood blob's integrity. The wall stops for the toilet, so I'm skeptical. Skepticism is a totally inadequate standard for deciding in the case of a load bearing wall, though.

Comment: The wall was not an outside wall.  I can't see the horizontal blocking being load bearing at all, just look at the left side where they 'meet' the stud.

Comment: The blocking seems to be held up with a 4x4 in the centre, holding more studs.  Not saying it was done right, but seems a lot of work if nothing.  Remove more drywall and see how the wall is built.

Comment: There's no 4x4. Not sure which you're referring to.

Comment: Some of the pictures make the wood look bigger, might be a vertical  2x4(picture looks like a 4x4).  The stud holding up the horizontal wood.  I know you don't want to cut out more drywall, but drywall repair is easy and will let us see what is under it.  It seems like too much wood for simple blocking/filling, even if done badly.

Comment: Yea its a 2x4.  I checked with a borescope, so the hand drawn diagram is accurate to what's under there.